# How to close cmd window after a batch job run

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Hi I have written a batch file which will run through a scheduler. The batch file job is to truncate the data from a file. But the problem I am facing here is after the batch file ran the cmd window is not closing automatically. That is why next time  scheduler won't able to run the batch job throwing an error" process can not access the file".

And also scheduler status is always showing "Running" .It should be " Ready" state after completion of job. but the here job is not completing as the cmd window is opened.

Can anyone help me out how to exit from cmd window?

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -noexit -Command "Clear-Content -Force E:\Logs\pgbouncer.log";
exit %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: You probably don't need to use [tag:powershell] for this. Why not just use something like this: `@CD.>"E:\Logs\pgbouncer.log"`?

Answer (score 1):

> -NoExit
>   Doesn't exit after running startup commands.

[Powershell.exe Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6)
You have -noexit switch enabled. Use:
`powershell.exe -Command "Clear-Content -Force E:\Logs\pgbouncer.log";`